# Two dropdown dynamic fields adding and removing for Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have two drop down custom time picker made with bootstrap 3.3.6 . I need to add and remove dynamicly custom time picker.

Here is the picture of the time picker.
[image: time picker]

And here you can find the code

```
<div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Time</label>


                                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">H</span>
                                                    <select class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="00">00</option>
                                                    <option value="01">01</option>
                                                    <option value="02">02</option>
                                                    <option value="03">03</option>
                                                    <option value="04">04</option>
                                                    <option value="05">05</option>
                                                    <option value="06">06</option>
                                                    <option value="07">07</option>
                                                    <option value="08">08</option>
                                                    <option value="09">09</option>
                                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                                    <option value="11">11</option>
                                                    <option value="12">12</option>
                                                    <option value="13">13</option>
                                                    <option value="14">14</option>
                                                    <option value="15">15</option>
                                                    <option value="16">16</option>
                                                    <option value="17">17</option>
                                                    <option value="18">18</option>
                                                    <option value="19">19</option>
                                                    <option value="20">20</option>
                                                    <option value="21">21</option>
                                                    <option value="22">22</option>
                                                    <option value="23">23</option>
                                                </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <span class="help-block">Hour</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">M</span>

                                                    <select class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="00">00</option>
                                                    <option value="05">05</option>
                                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                                    <option value="15">15</option>
                                                    <option value="20">20</option>
                                                    <option value="25">25</option>
                                                    <option value="30">30</option>
                                                    <option value="35">35</option>
                                                    <option value="40">40</option>
                                                    <option value="45">45</option>
                                                    <option value="50">50</option>
                                                    <option value="55">55</option>
                                                </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <span class="help-block">Minute</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                                <div class="input-group">

                                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button id="plus" class="btn btn-success add-field-1" type="button">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
          </button>
          </span>

                                                </div>

                                            </div>


                                        </div>
```

I am creating dynamic fields for one text field (that you can see the picture below) with this code

```
var template = '<div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control"/></div>',
    minusButton = '<span class="input-group-btn"><button id="minus" class="btn btn-danger delete-field" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button></span>';



$('.add-field').click(function() {
  var temp = $(template).insertBefore('.help-block');
  temp.append(minusButton);
});

$('.fields').on('click', '.delete-field', function(){
  $(this).parents('.input-group').first().remove();
});
```

[image]
when the case two different field, i couldnt manage how to do.

At my one text field add buton was sticked to field but in teh second one is seperate as i have two wild.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. You need only one add button instead of add button in all row elements. and you need to add one div to append dynamic elements

```js
$(document).on('click', '#plus', function(){
 
  var template = " <div class='form-group' id='extra'> " 
 +" <label class='col-md-3 control-label'>Time</label> " 
 +" <div class='col-md-1'> " 
 +" <div class='input-group'> " 
 +" <span class='input-group-addon'>H</span> " 
 +" <select class='form-control'> " 
 +" <option value='00'>00</option> " 
 +" <option value='01'>01</option> " 
 +" <option value='02'>02</option> " 
 +" <option value='03'>03</option> " 
 +" <option value='04'>04</option> " 
 +" <option value='05'>05</option> " 
 +" <option value='06'>06</option> " 
 +" <option value='07'>07</option> " 
 +" <option value='08'>08</option> " 
 +" <option value='09'>09</option> " 
 +" <option value='10'>10</option> " 
 +" <option value='11'>11</option> " 
 +" <option value='12'>12</option> " 
 +" <option value='13'>13</option> " 
 +" <option value='14'>14</option> " 
 +" <option value='15'>15</option> " 
 +" <option value='16'>16</option> " 
 +" <option value='17'>17</option> " 
 +" <option value='18'>18</option> " 
 +" <option value='19'>19</option> " 
 +" <option value='20'>20</option> " 
 +" <option value='21'>21</option> " 
 +" <option value='22'>22</option> " 
 +" <option value='23'>23</option> " 
 +" </select> " 
 +" </div> " 
 +" <span class='help-block'>Hour</span> " 
 +" </div> " 
 +"  " 
 +" <div class='col-md-1'> " 
 +" <div class='input-group'> " 
 +" <span class='input-group-addon'>M</span> " 
 +"  " 
 +" <select class='form-control'> " 
 +" <option value='00'>00</option> " 
 +" <option value='05'>05</option> " 
 +" <option value='10'>10</option> " 
 +" <option value='15'>15</option> " 
 +" <option value='20'>20</option> " 
 +" <option value='25'>25</option> " 
 +" <option value='30'>30</option> " 
 +" <option value='35'>35</option> " 
 +" <option value='40'>40</option> " 
 +" <option value='45'>45</option> " 
 +" <option value='50'>50</option> " 
 +" <option value='55'>55</option> " 
 +" </select> " 
 +" </div> " 
 +" <span class='help-block'>Minute</span> " 
 +"  " 
 +" <div class='col-md-1'> " 
 +" <div class='input-group'> " 
 +"  " 
 +" <span class='input-group-btn'> " 
 
 +" </button> <button id='minus' class='btn btn-danger delete-field' type='button'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></i></button></span> </div> "
+" </div> " 
 +" </div> " 
 +" </div> ";
  console.log("this");
   $('#dynamic').append(template);
  template="";
 
  //temp.append(minusButton);
});

$(document).on('click', '.delete-field', function(){
  console.log("re");
  $('#extra').first().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Time</label>


                                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">H</span>
                                                    <select class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="00">00</option>
                                                    <option value="01">01</option>
                                                    <option value="02">02</option>
                                                    <option value="03">03</option>
                                                    <option value="04">04</option>
                                                    <option value="05">05</option>
                                                    <option value="06">06</option>
                                                    <option value="07">07</option>
                                                    <option value="08">08</option>
                                                    <option value="09">09</option>
                                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                                    <option value="11">11</option>
                                                    <option value="12">12</option>
                                                    <option value="13">13</option>
                                                    <option value="14">14</option>
                                                    <option value="15">15</option>
                                                    <option value="16">16</option>
                                                    <option value="17">17</option>
                                                    <option value="18">18</option>
                                                    <option value="19">19</option>
                                                    <option value="20">20</option>
                                                    <option value="21">21</option>
                                                    <option value="22">22</option>
                                                    <option value="23">23</option>
                                                </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <span class="help-block">Hour</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">M</span>

                                                    <select class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="00">00</option>
                                                    <option value="05">05</option>
                                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                                    <option value="15">15</option>
                                                    <option value="20">20</option>
                                                    <option value="25">25</option>
                                                    <option value="30">30</option>
                                                    <option value="35">35</option>
                                                    <option value="40">40</option>
                                                    <option value="45">45</option>
                                                    <option value="50">50</option>
                                                    <option value="55">55</option>
                                                </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <span class="help-block">Minute</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                                <div class="input-group">

                                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button id="plus" class="btn btn-success add-field-1" type="button">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
          </button>
          </span>

                                                </div>

                                            </div>


                                        </div>

<div id="dynamic"></div>
```

Comment: there is a problem it clones too much. and adds a add button extra. I have removed the add button and the result here http://www.a1b5.net/metro/admin/dinotime.php

Comment: you can see the result from the same url

Comment: @JosePinheiro  its working ryt? select option visibility you need to change col size from col-md-1 to col-md-2

Comment: remove button is not in order